# Stacking TextBlock Controls in WPF

Tags: wpf

i have kept textblocks one below the other.
For e.g.
            `<textBlock1>
            <textBlock2>
            <textBlock3>
            <textBlock4>`
Any Textblock (say-'textBlock2') in between is visible=Hidden, then automatically following Textblocks(say-'textBlock3','textBlock4') should shift up. Also, when the textbox(say-'textBlock2') which is visible=Hidden is made visible, then following textboxes (say-'textBlock3','textBlock4')  should shift downwards...
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `Visibility` to `Collapsed`, not `Hidden`, for that to happen.

Comment: But when Visibility is set to Hidden, it shows gape in between textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, wrap the textblocks in a StackPanel

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx

Comment: But when Visibility is set to Hidden, it shows gape in between textboxes.

Comment: You want to set the Visibility to Collapsed.